# In django what's the difference between form.errors['field_name'] and form['field_name'].errors?

Tags: python, django, forms

```
>>> f = ContactForm({'subject': 'Hello', 'message': ''})
>>> f.errors['message']
>>> [u'This field is required.']
>>> f['message'].errors
>>> [u'This field is required.']
```

What's the difference b/w the 3rd & 5th line ? Do they have different purposes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `f['message'].errors`, you are using the [`BoundField.errors`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L450) property.

If you look at the source, you can see that `BoundField.errors` tries to fetch the error list from the form's errors if it exists.

```
@property
def errors(self):
    """
    Returns an ErrorList for this field. Returns an empty ErrorList
    if there are none.
    """
    return self.form.errors.get(self.name, self.form.error_class())
```

In the case that there are no errors for the field, the `BoundField.error` property returns an empty error list, so the behaviour is slightly different.

```
>>> f = ContactForm({'subject': 'Hello', 'message': 'world!'})
>>> f.errors
{}
>>> f.errors['message']
KeyError
>>> f['message'].errors
>>> []
```

Having this errors property on the field makes it easy to loop through a form's fields in the template, and display the errors.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```